# SSL pinning flutter using Dio package throws HandshakeException

Tags: flutter, dio, sslpinning

I have pinned (the Facebook SSL certificate) in the assets/certificates path.

I am fetching network calls using Dio package.

```
void fetchDataUsingDio() async {
final dio = Dio();
ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load(_certificatePath);

(dio.httpClientAdapter as DefaultHttpClientAdapter).onHttpClientCreate =
    (client) {
  SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContext();
  client.badCertificateCallback =
      (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => false; //added
  securityContext.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(bytes.buffer.asUint8List());
 
  return HttpClient(context: securityContext);
};

try {
  var response = await dio.get(_baseUrl);
  print(response.data);
} catch (error) {
  if (error is DioError) {
    print(error.toString());
  } else {
    print('Unexpected Error');
  }
}
```

}

The base URL and cert path were

```
  final String _baseUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/";
  final String _certificatePath = "assets/certificates/fb.pem";
```

It worked the first time but after I tried to hit network call it throws

> HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:
> CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer
> certificate(handshake.cc:393))

Also, I Tried

**MyHttpOverrides**

Can anyone guide me to implement SSL pinning in the flutter app securely?